# Drawing line from plane edge Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw a line from one object to a target object. I have managed to do this however the lines are drawn from the centers

What I would like to do is draw the lines from the edge of a plane to the edge of a plane on the target

[image: screenshot]

In this image the white lines are the currently drawn connection and the red lines are how I would like the lines to be drawn

This is how the lines are drawn right now

```
    foreach (GameObject planet in LinkedPlanets)
    {
        GameObject PlanetLine = new GameObject();
        PlanetLine.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        PlanetLine.name = this.transform.name + " To " + planet.transform.name;
        PlanetLine.transform.parent = this.transform;
        PlanetLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = PlanetLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
        lr.SetWidth(3f, 3f);
        lr.SetPosition(0, this.transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, planet.transform.position);
        lr.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_TintColor", new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.2f));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not tested, so may be wrong.

**EDIT:**

I see that you want to connect from edges of plane, so all change is instead of having direction vector from one planet to other, is to have direction based on longer axis of this vector. If the "x" is longer then "z" use `Vector3.right` multiplied by unary operator which depends on if the direction vector was below zero or not.

**END OF EDIT**

You need to know the radius of each circle. Let's say that in this example you know it, and it is 5f and 4f. Then you need to calculate the "meeting" points. You can do it like this:

```
foreach (GameObject planet in LinkedPlanets)
    {
        float radiusA = 5f;
        float radiusB = 4f;

        GameObject PlanetLine = new GameObject();
        PlanetLine.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        PlanetLine.name = this.transform.name + " To " + planet.transform.name;
        PlanetLine.transform.parent = this.transform;
        PlanetLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = PlanetLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
        lr.SetWidth(3f, 3f);

        Vector3 pointA = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (planet.transform.position - this.transform.position, radiusA);

        Vector3 pointB = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (this.transform.position -planet.transform.position, radiusB);

        lr.SetPosition(0, this.transform.position + pointA);
        lr.SetPosition(1, planet.transform.position + pointB);
        lr.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_TintColor", new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.2f));
}
```

So let's explain.

First you need to get the direction vector like:

```
planet.transform.position - this.transform.position
```

then clamp its length to end on radius length:

```
Vector3 pointA = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (planet.transform.position - this.transform.position, radiusA);
```

And finally add this vector to the actuall position:

```
this.transform.position + pointA
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i have tried this solution, i think that it would work if the points didn't need to touch the plane or the circle.
How would i get the line to go from the edge of the plane or the edge of the circle. 

The plane and the circle around the planet are separate things, the circle is drawn at run time with a line render and the plane is just a plain for raycasts
Here is the result with the code you suggested 
http://imgur.com/FT8Av1i